# Real time search Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have been table site for some time now and i implemented a searching system, but i want it to be real time search so whenever you press a button it will refresh the site. I have little coding experiance so ill ask for some help here.

Here is my ajax code:

```
function searchDomains() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Ajax/searchDomain.action.php",
        data: {
            domain: $('input[name="domain"]').val(),
            width: $(window).width()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#container_domains").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right, but you need to attach this function to the `keyup` event of the `<input />` and make it unobtrusive too:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
<div id="container_domains"></div>
```

And in the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $("#search").keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Ajax/searchDomain.action.php",
      data: {
        domain: $('input[name="domain"]').val(),
        width: $(window).width()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#container_domains").html(data).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: or bind to the `oninput` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput

Comment: @CodeiSir `oninput`? Okay... Good idea too. Has less support on IE. Not supported in IE < 9.

Comment: @CodeiSir The URL is wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput. **Doesn't work on IE < 9.** Period.

Comment: @CodeiSir Why do you repeat things? How is `input` better than `keyup`? One good reason please?

Comment: OK sorry, it's just a little more responsive. Oninput will catch every "symbol" as it's put into the `<input>`. Keyup will then only trigger when a key is released, wich is just a little later, or in a case where you keep the key pressed it will not trigger for quite some time.

Comment: @CodeiSir Gotcha... Thanks for the insight. `:)`

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, something i am doing wrong with replacing the code? nvm got it to work thanks!

Comment: @Leifus All the best. Enjoy! `:)`